# How to move my actionbar in my own dedicated view

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-view, android-actionmode

i create an actionMode like this :

```
ActionMode am = myActivity.startActionMode(callback);
```

then i try do do

```
am.setCustomView(this);
```

and i receive the error: The specified child already has a parent. you must call removeView() on the child's parent first

but here i don't understand because:

```
am.getCustomView()
```

return null ! so how it's possible i have the error saying the specified child already has a parent ?

How i can do to move my actionbar in my own dedicated view ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the Toolbar, I also assume you are using the  AppCompatActivity and have replaced the built in ActionBar with your custom Toolbar using  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
First of all ensure you are importing the correct namespace.

import android.support.v7.view.ActionMode;
and NOT

import android.view.ActionMode;
then use

_actionMode = startSupportActionMode(this);
and NOT

_actionMode = startActionMode(this);